# Discord Bot program won't add loot to database

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am trying to make a discord bot that plays a RPG game, but ihave come to an issue where,upon trying to update a .json database, it doesn't add the items. Here is the relevant parts of the code

```
# Load the JSON database

def load_database():

    if not database_exists():

        return {'players': {}}

    with open(DATABASE_FILE, 'r') as file:

        try:

            data = json.load(file)

        except json.JSONDecodeError:

            data = {'players': {}}

        return data

# Save the JSON database

def save_database(data):

    with open(DATABASE_FILE, 'w') as file:

        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

```
def add_item(player_id, item):
    database = load_database()
    player = database['players'][player_id]
    if 'inventory' not in player:
        player['inventory'] = {}  # Initialize an empty inventory dictionary if it doesn't exist

    item_id = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Generate a unique ID for the item
    item['id'] = item_id
    player['inventory'][item_id] = item  # Add the item to the player's inventory
```

```
            )

        if player['health'] <= 0:
            await ctx.send(
                f'<@{player_id}>, you were defeated by the {monster["name"]}!')
            for member_id in player['party']:
                await ctx.send(
                    f'<@{member_id}>, your party member {ctx.author.mention} was defeated in battle!'
                )
        else:
            await ctx.send(
                f'<@{player_id}>, you defeated the {monster["name"]}!')
            for item in monster['loot']:
                item_id = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Generate a unique ID for the item
                item['id'] = item_id
                player['inventory'][item_id] = item  # Add the item to the player's inventory
                if item['type'] == 'currency':
                    player['currency'] += item['value']
                await ctx.send(f'{item["name"]}')
            save_database(load_database())
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'<@{player_id}>, you need to create a character first!')
```

I've tried ChatGPT but it can't fix it. Any ideas?

When I use the /battle command, it starts the battle sequence, after the monster us defeated it says the item has been added, and I check the.json and it hasn't been added.

Comment: ```save_database(load_database())``` loads the database and then saves the save information.  Unfortunately, when you run ```load_database()```, you probably overwrites any changes you have in memory.  I think what you need is ```save_database(database)``` or some such.

Comment: Will try and test, will report back

Comment: Still not working properly, I hate my stupid code